# Import CSV to MySQL

Tags: mysql, csv, load-data-infile

I have created a database and a table. I have also created all the fields I will be needing. I have created 46 fields including one that is my ID for the row. The CSV doesn't contain the ID field, nor does it contain the headers for the columns. I am new to all of this but have been trying to figure this out. I'm not on here being lazy asking for the answer, but looking for directions.

I'm trying to figure out how to import the CSV but have it start importing data starting at the 2nd field, since I'm hoping the auto_increment will fill in the ID field, which is the first field I created.

I tried these instructions with no luck. Can anyone offer some insight?

1. The column names of your CSV file must match those of your table
2. Browse to your required .csv file
3. Select CSV using LOAD DATA options
4. Check box 'ON' for *Replace table data with file*
5. In *Fields terminated by* box, type `,`
6. In *Fields enclosed by* box, `"`
7. In *Fields escaped by* box, `\`
8. In *Lines terminated by* box, `auto`
9. In *Column names* box, type column name separated by `,` like `column1,column2,column3`
10. Check box ON for *Use LOCAL keyword*.

Edit:

The CSV file is 32.4kb

The first row of my CSV is:

```
Test Advertiser,23906032166,119938,287898,,585639051,287898 - Engager - 300x250,88793551,Running,295046551,301624551,2/1/2010,8/2/2010,Active,,Guaranteed,Publisher test,Maintainer test,example-site.com,,All,All,,Interest: Dental; custom geo zones: City,300x250,-,CPM,$37.49 ,"4,415","3,246",3,0,$165.52 ,$121.69 ,"2,895",805,0,0,$30.18 ,$37.49 ,0,$0.00 ,IMPRESSIONBASED,NA,USD
```

Comment: Have you tried using PHPMyAdmin?

Comment: @Kerry: He's listing phpMyAdmin instructions, so I'd say yes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the instructions i posted are what i used in phpMyAdmin but my information gets thrown off. I read somewhere that they best way to do this is to have the column headers on the csv reflect the fields in my table. is this correct?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can have MySQL set values for certain columns during import. If your `id` field is set to auto increment, you can set it to null during import and MySQL will then assign incrementing values to it. Try putting something like this in the SQL tab in phpMyAdmin:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'path/to/file.csv' INTO TABLE your_table FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' SET id=null;
```

Answer (score 17):

Please look at this page and see if it has what you are looking for. Should be all you need since you are dealing with just one table. [MYSQL LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)

So for example you might do something like this:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'filepath' INTO TABLE 'tablename' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (column2, column3, column4);
```

That should give you an idea. There are of course more options that can be added as seen in the above link.

Comment: Thank you I will give this a go and see if i can figure it out. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

be sure to use LOAD DATA **LOCAL** INFILE if the import file is local. :)

Comment: Not if file is already local. Using LOCAL can introduce other  problems, e.g. "ERROR 1148 (42000): The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version", what does not necessary means MySQL version incompability [discussion about this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/loading-tables.html).  Using LOCAL might require checking additional settings, e.g. on client and server side of the flag: local-infile. For me it still did not work.