# Larg set of csv files need to be inserted into a database

Tags: php, mysql, performance, csv, bigdata

I was requested to do a csv -> mysql insert on CSV Files .

They have 20k files of csv that contains from 100 to 100k lines of data .

So here is what i thought i can do :

On my machine i could join all files into 1 using a simple command :

```
 copy *.csv  combined.csv
```

and then process that file  and then using php fgetcsv process that file and insert it in the DB .

**Or**

I could write a php program that read a directory process each file and when done transfer it into another folder .

Dedicated server is available

Good Pc with 8gb of memory available

What do you suggest ?

Comment: regardless of whether you combine the files or not, you want to import them via [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025648/import-csv-to-mysql)

Comment: You should have left that as an answer :)

Comment: no, because if that answers your question already, your question is a duplicate and should be closed ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html). Its better to  insert data file by file.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/data.csv' 
INTO TABLE `table` 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Run in batch mode for 20k files. Put password in command to prevent it from asking.

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in /path/to/*.csv;
do 
    mysql -uroot -pPASSWORD DATABASE \
    -e "LOAD DATA INFILE '$f' 
        INTO TABLE `table` 
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
        LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'"
    echo $f is imported ...
done;
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be a much better idea to do it file by file.  This allows for restart if something goes wrong, also, are all the files identical?

You can use a php script to generate sql commands and execute those .