# Import CSV file directly into MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, csv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Import CSV to mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025648/import-csv-to-mysql)

Right I need some help with this:

I am trying to import a .csv file into a mysql database using php, rather than doing it manually through phpmyadmin.

This is the code I have at the moment:

```
if($_REQUEST['func'] == "iid"){
    $db->conn = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) or 
                      die('There was a problem connecting to the database.');
    $csv = $_POST['csv-file'];
    $path = $csv;
    $row = 1;
    if (($handle = fopen($path, "r")) !== FALSE) {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
            $row++;
            $data_entries[] = $data ;

        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
    // this you'll have to expand
    foreach($data_entries as $line){
        $sql = $db->conn->prepare('INSERT INTO `bd_results`');

        $db->execute($line);
    }
}
```

However I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::execute() in /homepages/19/d372249701/htdocs/business-sites/bowlplex-doubles-new/admin/scores.php on line 44
```

For reference I am using this code taken from: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4143938/import-csv-file-directly-into-mysql)

I am not well versed in the $db->conn business I'm used to mysql_connect!! so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you get if you use $db->conn->execute() ? - rephrase - is it $db or $db->conn that's the database object?

Comment: @MyStream `Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli::execute() in /homepages/19/d372249701/htdocs/business-sites/bowlplex-doubles-new/admin/scores.php on line 44`

Comment: That's better =) that's the object you need - but see below for the right syntax to use for the query.

Comment: Did you consider using LOAD DATA INFILE? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this simple one.

```
if (($handle = fopen("google.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $db->conn->query("INSERT INTO values('" . implode('\',\'', $data) . "');");
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Your script might also need to add quotes to the CSV values if they don't have quotes already. If you'll be needing to deal with quotes and all in your CSV files, I recommend you look at my blog post at http://www.fusionswift.com/2012/07/php-import-csv-to-mysql/

Comment: All I get is this `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1` using `$db->conn->error`

Comment: I am using ; as the delimeter and "" as quotes what do I change

Comment: What does your CSV look like? Theoretically the new code should work.

Comment: Example Row 1 : `1;"LAURA";"OBRIEN";0;"WATFORD";161;1;104836;263;"F";"14/09/1995";186;147;173;133;210;192;164;148;1353;169.1;3083`

Comment: In `while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {`, change the `","` to `";"` and that should work

Comment: No errors. but it is missing the first record?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13824/discussion-between-tech163-and-david-passmore)

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($data_entries as $line) {
    $stmt = $db->conn->prepare('INSERT INTO `bd_results` (field1, field2) VALUES (?, ?)');
    $stmt->bindParam('ss', $field1Value, $field2Value);
    list($field1Value, $field2Value) = $line
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Where $field1Value is first CSV column, $field2Value is second CSV column and both are of type string, specified as such in `bindParam()` method.

Basically you will need to prepare the query in its entirety, then you can assign variables to it, and once the variables have desired values you execute the query using `execute()` method.

This is how you use prepared statements. Personally I'd go with Mahn's suggestion though and avoid using prepared statements for such a task unless you need to process the data while on it.

[mysqli_stmt::bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)
[mysqli_stmt::execute](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)