# insert data from csv file to mysql using php

Tags: php, cakephp, csv

I have the csv file `mail.csv` that contain data as below:

```
   type,timeLogged,t
d,2012-08-24 00:00:57+0200,2012-08-24 00:00:45+0200,noreply@news.camera-factice.com,myriam.yall34@gmail.com,
d,2012-08-24 00:00:57+0200,2012-08-24 00:00:45+0200,noreply@118-bonsplans.com,toulouse@texa.fr,
b,2012-08-24 00:00:57+0200,2012-08-22 23:59:31+0200,noreply@lemeilleur-duweb.com
d,2012-08-24 00:00:57+0200,2012-08-24 00:00:57+0200,diffusion@news.antivol-voiture.com
```

I want to insert all these data into mysql using php.In fact I don not know how to fix this.Anyone help me please,Many thanks,

Comment: please have a look on this post  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461313/import-csv-file-directly-into-mysql-database?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [CakePHP Utils Plugin](https://github.com/CakeDC/utils) that includes a `CsvImportBehavior`. You just need to pass the csv file path. And its method (`$this->Model->importCSV('mail.csv');`) will return you the array containing all records. Then you can simply manipulate it according to your requirement and can save into the database very easily.

Comment: I also used it. And it fulfilled all my needs. I was also supposed to give this suggestion. :)