# ATK4: import CSV into database using CLI?

Tags: csv, import, atk4, agiletoolkit

I'm asking for a short, clean example to build from...

I'm new to atk4 and have been working my way through tutorials (etc) - and am also fairly new with PHP etc.. so few things are 'obvious' to me at this point.  I have created CRUD screens for all the tables, set up mySQL, and have it all working well; love ATK!

What I have not seen is a simple, minimalist example of how to import a CSV into a DB table - leveraging the power of atk4 which makes things so much simpler.

It seems like a great opportunity to use the CLI, point it at a file, load a model, and insert into a table.

Thanks in advance,

Mark

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025648/import-csv-to-mysql

Comment: Looks perfect, thank you!  I'll give that a shot.  Have you run across an example using atk?  Mark

Comment: That have nothing to do with ATK actually. Just use MySQLs LOAD DATA INFILE syntax. Of course you can inject this in some ATK sourcecode, but if this is a one time job to do, then use just mysql commandline :)

Comment: I installed the phpMyAdmin toolkit over the weekend - and loaded some spreadsheets into the DB. Nice tool.  I thought the atk4 might come in handy to do the same, but manage the conversion from plain data (say 'Terms' such as 'Net 30') to a second table through a foreign key (TermsID instead) - with a separate table that contains a list of valid Terms... you get the idea.   Thanks again, Mark

Comment: As I said before - that's no way related with ATK4 as far as I understand your question & comments.

Comment: For advanced MySQL DB management try MySQL WorkBench. It have some bugs, but it's very nice and useful. Especially when you need to synchronize your DB structure with models etc.

Comment: I've loaded both MySQL WorkBench and phpMyAdmin - each has it's merits (thank you). phpMyAdmin has the import CSV utility built right in, and it works quite well. In particular, I like that you can give it a list of the fields such that you can load one subset of the table's columns from CSV-A, another from CSV-B, etc. I appreciate your assistance - Thanks. Mark