# Processing large csv file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sidekiq

I have a large CSV file with a lot of data more than 75000 records. I need to insert it into a mysql database from my rails application. Using background processing using Sidekiq (https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq‎) is also taking a lot of time. 
Any better way to process the data ?

Thanks

Comment: This is a MySQL "load data" question, not Rails. Try: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html

Comment: if you need to read to file, then process something on the data and then save that proccessed data to the database you should try to optimize your code, I don't think it's sidekiq's fault, sidekiq only runs your code, you can try delayed_job or resque, but I think the problem is your processing algorithm (i.e. try to optimize validations, first validate the fields that will be faster, don't just run "valid?" on a model, if any fast validations fails just skip that record)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it directly on mysql without using rails. It will be much faster that way. Have a look at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025648/import-csv-to-mysql) for more information

Answer (score 0):

Use MySql Function:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.txt' INTO TABLE tbl_name
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```