# Import 2000 email adresses in MySQL phpMyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, email, phpmyadmin

I have an excel file with 2000 email addresses, each line has an e-mail address.
But how can I import all those Email Addresses into a table in phpymadmin?

I have already created a database and a table, this is the structure:

DatabaseName: myname_clients

DatabaseTable: clients

Columns:

ID, NAME, EMAIL, TEL

I have tried to import emails with a CSV file but no results, I hope that someone has a solution for me.

Comment: What is the issue? Is the file too big??

Comment: No its not big, i just get a error, can not import.. I think because in the CSV file each email adres is on one line?

Comment: What is the error? Please include it in your question.

Comment: What are you actually doing to import the file? A query, a file input in PMA? Some custom PHP? Also can you provide an example (redacted  / changed version) of the CSV file you're trying to import.

Comment: I am trying to import this CSV in my database : http://i.imgur.com/ZZtbWaV.png @JonStirling Thank you very much

Comment: I meant _how_ are you importing it. What mechanism are you using.

Comment: @JonStirling I was trying to import the emailadresses with PhpMyAdmin -> Upload File, but that is not working, so that is why i ask this question, how can i import 2k emails the best way into a table in phpmyadmin ? i was thinking for about creating a php page, and past there al the email adresses and press send? so that the emails will go into the database? or can i do it by a better way?

Comment: @MissesSalima. Try to use a MySQL script based on [it](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html). [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077801/import-csv-to-mysql-table) [are](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4143938/import-csv-file-directly-into-mysql) [some](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025648/import-csv-to-mysql) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635166/how-to-import-csv-file-to-mysql-table) in SO that can help you. Remember to ensure the match between the CSV file and the table columns.